# Почему не могу запустить VM?

Tags: linux, debian, proxmox

Запускаю виртуальную машину, выходит такая вот ошибка. С чем может быть связана?

no physical interface on bridge 'vmbr1'

kvm: network script /var/lib/qemu-server/pve-bridge failed with status 6400

TASK ERROR: start failed: QEMU exited with code 1

Comment: Там же всё написано. Google translate, и вперёд! (Говорит, что не находит физического интерфейса для создания сетевого моста. Самое простое, наверное, выключить поддержку сети, только это часто и самое бесполезное решение.)

Comment: мост то можно без физики создать, странный проксмокс